# Is it possible that the tangent can look like this

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

Consider this:

$$ K(v) = \frac{v}{v^2+9} $$

Approximate the function for v = 1 by a tangent. I first did the derivitave of the function.

$$ K'(v) = \frac{-v^2+9}{(v^2+9)^2} $$ And now the tangent formula

$$ t(v) = f'(v) * (v - v0) + f(v) $$
Now if I input 1 in both K and K' I get this

$$K'(v) = \frac{-1^2+9}{(1^2+9)^2} $$ That should be 1/10 for K we also get 1/10. Now if I put that in the tangent formula

$$ t(v) = \frac{1}{10} * (v - 1) + \frac{1}{10} $$ Now when I multiply this I only have 1/10v left since 1/10 - 1/10 is 0. Is it possible to have a tangent looking like this,or did I make an error somwhere along the lines.

Thank you!

Comment: The last term in your tangent formula should be $f(x_0)$, not $f(x)$. (And $x$ should be $v$, or vice versa.)

Comment: Your calculation of $K'(1)=\frac{8}{100}$ is astray. Also you've jumbled up $v$s and $x$s

Comment: So only three errors so far...

Comment: Okay that mit vs and xs is a bit confusing,Ill fix that real quick.Also will recheck my calculation of K'(1)

Comment: derivative at $v=1$ is $2/15$ not $1/10$, because you have $-1^2=-1$ and not $+1$.  This is your mistake. @codeisfun

Comment: Well I have calculated that it is +1. Here is my calculation in detail. $$ K'(1) = \frac{1+9}{1^2+2*1*9+9^2}  $$ That should be 1/100 but obviously im wrong somewhere.

Comment: $-1^2$ is $-1$, not $+1$. It means $-(1^2)$, not $(-1)^2$. (So now we're up to four errors.)

Comment: Oh now it makes sence,thanks. And errors happen I dont know why you keep pointing that out I thought the point of the this was to help someone correct their errors,if I was perfect in math I wouldnt post the question would I? Also,if the errors bother you so much just dont look at the post.

Comment: If my comments bother you so much, don't look at them.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

near $ v_0=1 $, we have the approximation

$$K(1+\epsilon)\approx t(1+\epsilon)$$

or

$$K(1+\epsilon)\approx K'(1)(1+\epsilon-1)+K(1)$$
and

$$K(1+\epsilon)\approx \frac{\epsilon}{25}+\frac{1}{10}$$